# how to be sure that the visualization is updated with css changes via javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, redraw

example..

```
<input type="button" value="click me" id="p1">

<script>
 document.querySelector("#p1").onclick = function () {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    alert(`My background color is ${this.style.backgroundColor} ??`);
  }
</script>
```

The alert write My background color is green but at the moment of alert the color is gray!!

I know many ways to get around this:

- don't use alert but show a div..
- use setTimeout
- use sleep function with async await ([What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep))

..but is a way to be sure that the browser rendering is done?

Answer (score 1):

You could use requestAnimationFrame - similar to setTimeout except the browser will take care of the timing as the function is run before a repaint.

A simple example:

```js
function tellMe() {
  alert(`My background color is ${document.querySelector('#p1').style.backgroundColor} ??`);
}
document.querySelector("#p1").onclick = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(tellMe)
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click me" id="p1">
```